# Pub/Sub push notifications for Cloud Storage on a folder level

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-pubsub

I have been developing an event driven processing flow where (ideally)

- content is uploaded into a Cloud Storage bucket, one folder at a time
- I then want to use the folder name to access *some* of the files inside such folders
- a cloud function is triggered *once* per folder uploaded and will be using the files above
- the cloud function will then publish its result

I enabled Pub/Sub push notification from a Cloud Storage bucket on event type `OBJECT_FINALIZE` and I would like to have *one notification per folder*. However, when I look at the number of messages produced I see there are as many messages as the number of items in the uploaded folder.

I read about the [flat structure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49068917/4146521) of a bucket and this might be a problem as the lambda function will be triggered many more times than necessary.

Is there any way to limit the push notification to **one per folder**?

NB: every folder has a different name, and there might be two folders uploaded at the same time.

Comment: Sadly, not yet (But stay tuned!!). Today, you have to implement a filter by yourselves when your app handle the event.

Comment: Storage notifications are for whole buckets: you cannot trigger a notification for some paths. If you cannot use different buckets and want to mitigate excessive calls, take a look at cloud run : depending on the workload the bill can be lower.